# Sum of finite series using LaTeX 3

Tags: calculations, latex3, xparse

Is it possible to calculate the value of a finite series, say,

[image: sum]

using LaTeX 3?

Comment: Yes, but why? ;-)

Comment: @egreg I would like to create an example sheet with quite a lot of different finite sums and their values. If LaTeX 3 can handle the calculations, I can change them without forgetting to calculate their (new) values.

Comment: But you can do the above and much much more and more easily as well, using a computer algebra system, then export the results to Latex at the end.

Comment: @Nasser That might be but the case I would like to use LaTeX for the task. I am using Mathematica 10 but that's not the point. `:)` egreg's solution is/was what I am/was looking for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes, you can, and pretty easily too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\computesum}{mmm}
 {% pass control to an internal function
  \svend_compute_sum:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

% a variable for storing the partial sums
\fp_new:N \l_svend_partial_sum_fp

\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_compute_sum:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  % clear the variable
  \fp_zero:N \l_svend_partial_sum_fp
  % for k from #1 to #2 ...
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    % ... add the current value to the partial sum so far
    \fp_add:Nn \l_svend_partial_sum_fp { #3 }
   }
  % deliver the value
  \fp_use:N \l_svend_partial_sum_fp
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\computesum{0}{0}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{1}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{2}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{3}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{4}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{5}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{6}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{7}{#1^2}$\par
$\computesum{0}{8}{#1^2}$\par
\end{document}
```

Note that in the third argument `#1` stands for the summation index.

In the example, `#1^2` is passed as `#3` to `\svend_compute_sum:nnn`; since the argument is used inside `\int_step_inline:nnnn`, where `#1` stands for the current index, the magic happens. `;-)`

The argument should be legal code for floating point expressions. So no hope to evaluate factorials unless you define them yourself.

[image]

If your summands are always integers, you can change all `fp` into `int`.

If you load also `siunitx` and change the internal function into

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \svend_compute_sum:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \fp_zero:N \l_svend_partial_sum_fp
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 }
   {
    \fp_add:Nn \l_svend_partial_sum_fp { #3 }
   }
  \num { \fp_use:N \l_svend_partial_sum_fp }
 }
```

then

```
$\computesum{0}{300}{#1^2}$
```

will print like

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Just a single thing: I would like the digits in the output value to be grouped in three as with the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Easy enough: add `\num` as shown in the edit.

Comment: Would it be faster if `\fp_set:Nx` was used with the `\int_step_function:…` *inside* the argument (so it expands before `l3fp` does the computing)?

Comment: @Manuel `\int_step_inline:nnnn` is not expandable. One could consider `\int_step_function:nnnN`, but I don't think it would be much faster.

Comment: @egreg Any chance I can make you (1) optimize the speed of the code [your conversation with Manuel suggests that it isn't at the moment] and (2) comment the code [I'm trying to understand what's going on]?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg About the speed I don't think one can do much better. Evaluating all summands and then doing a giant `\fp_eval:n` doesn't seem faster at all. I'll add a few comments.

Comment: @PierPaolo The advantage is that you can use any legal expression in the third argument, where `#1` stands for the current index. So `$\computesum{0}{30}{2*#1}$` computes the sum of the first 30 even numbers.

Answer (score 10):

You may load [xintexpr](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) for this, and allow `LaTeX3` some rest.

> [image: sums]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hscale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{shortvrb}

\begin{document}

$$\sum_{i=1}^{300} i^2=\num{\xinttheexpr add(i^2, i=1..300)\relax }$$

% For some reason, this doesn't go through:
% \num{\xintthefloatexpr [14] add(1/i^2,i=1..50)\relax}
% one needs to first expand the \num argument:
% \expandafter\num\expandafter
%     {\romannumeral-`0\xintthefloatexpr [14] add(1/i^2,i=1..50)\relax}
%

The float version does each addition with 16 digits floats, hence the last
digit may be a bit off.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{50} \frac1{i^2}=
  \xintFrac{\xinttheexpr reduce(add(1/i^2,i=1..50))\relax}
  \approx  \xintthefloatexpr add(1/i^2,i=1..50)\relax$$

If one has anyhow computed an exact value, it is better to deduce the
float from it rather than evaluating the sum as a sum of floats.

\noindent\verb|\oodef\MySum {\xinttheexpr reduce(-add((-1)^i/i^2,i=1..50))\relax }|

\oodef\MySum {\xinttheexpr reduce(-add((-1)^i/i^2,i=1..50))\relax }

$$\sum_{i=1}^{50} \frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^2}=
\xintFrac{\MySum}$$
\verb|$$\xintDigits:=48; \approx\xintthefloatexpr \MySum\relax$$|
$$\xintDigits:=48; \approx\xintthefloatexpr \MySum\relax$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Really nice, jfbu. Thank you for the contribution!

Comment: However, if you need `sin`, `cos`, `exp`, `log` they are not implemented yet in `xintexpr`, only `sqrt` is. The `\xintthefloatexpr\MySum\relax` thing is a bit inefficient as it will first expand `\MySum` then parse its (longish) numerator and denominator digit by digit. Better is `\xintFloat [48]{\MySum}` or the slightly prettier `\xintPFloat [48]{\MySum}` (due to oversight, this `\xintPFloat` is not documented a.t.t.o.w in `xint.pdf`). Both can serve as arguments to `siunitx`'s `\num` macro. For computations with only integers you can use `\xinttheiiexpr ...\relax`. `/` = rounded division