# Implementing the Sum Function in TeX

Tags: tex-core

How would I go about implementing a function in TeX to add an arbitrary number of numbers? Reading through the `\def` notes, it seems it can only take up to nine arguments. How would I make a function that adds together an optionally arbitrarily large list of numbers?

Comment: Perhaps a Recursive `\def` like lists are implemented, within a copy to another temporary `\def` ( a length most probably) is needed)

Comment: You should be more specific in terms of the input requirements. So, mock up some example *and* show what you've tried.

Comment: Related (like a distant cousin): [Sum of finite series](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216436/5764)

Comment: @Werner I suppose I should have asked a more basic question then, I'm still really trying to figure out how TeX works, and I was hoping seeing something like this would get me started.

Comment: @Anthony: Sure, but in terms of the input you  have to be specific. For example, if you want to add an arbitrary number of values, just use `\calc{1+2+3+4+5+6+...+1000+1001+1002+...}` where `\calc` is from LaTeX/`expl3` (`\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff`).

Comment: Oh, that's nice. What does the last part of that message mean, and where can I find an implementation of `\calc`?

Comment: @Anthony: [This is how you would use it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RLqPe.png)...

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong word- I didn't want a way to use it, I wanted to know how it was defined.

Comment: TeX's not really set up for doing mathematics (it's good at _typesetting_ maths!). As Werner says, you'll need to tighten up the spec of what you want to achieve. For example, are we talking integers or floating-point values, and if so how many digits? Do you need an expandable solution (one that can be used inside a context that 'expects' a number)? Can we use e-TeX/pdfTeX/LuaTeX or do you want a solution for Knuth's TeX? As indicated, a mock-up of the use case(s) and expected results would be very handy.

Comment: As a guide, implementing the FPU for `expl3` uses about 5000 lines of code, is expandable and uses both e-TeX and a pdfTeX primitive.  There are non-expandable maths systems in the `fp` package and `pgfmath`: again both run to 1000s of lines. All three of these cover a lot more than addition, but even that probably needs 100s of lines. Doing the same thing in LuaTeX is trivial as Lua handles the maths.

Comment: I know TeX isn't meant for this, but I know it *can* do it... What I had in mind is just something that can add integers. I was really hoping for some idea, any idea, of how to start this- so really I was hoping some more knowledgeable person would use their discretion to make a particularly illuminating education example.

Comment: You could possibly do it with [lambda-lists](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/lambda-lists) using `\Foldr` and e-tex `\numexpr`.

Comment: Perhaps, not what you want, but you can do it with lists in plain TeX (c.f., The Texbook, page 378): \newcount\temp
\def\\#1{\advance\temp by #1\relax}

\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}

\showthe\temp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will answer on the assumption that the input will be of the form

```
\addintegers{1 + 2 + 3}
```

*i.e.* consisting of a series of integers separated by `+` symbols and (potentially) whitespace. I'm also going to assume the solution does not need to be expandable, that we have only the TeX3 primitives available, and that we do not have to worry about 'big' values (larger than can be held by a `\count` register).

To find the sum here we need to set up a loop over the input, grabbing one number at a time. As we know that `+` comes between each number, the way to do that is to use a macro of the form

```
\def\foo#1+{% Code
```

as this will grab everything up to the next `+`. We then need to make sure that there is a `+` after the user input and that we have some 'marker' there we can test for as 'end-of-loop'. To do the actual maths, TeX provides `\count` registers: I'll use a scratch on inside a group and emit the result outside of the group using `\expandafter`:

```
\catcode`\@=11 %
\def\addintegers#1{%
  \begingroup
    \count0=0\relax
    \addintegers@aux#1+\relax+\relax
}
\def\addintegers@aux#1+{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax
    \expandafter\addintegers@end
  \else
    \advance\count0 by #1\relax
    \expandafter\addintegers@aux
  \fi
}
\def\addintegers@end#1\relax{%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \number\count0 %
}
\catcode`\@=12 %
\addintegers{1}
\addintegers{1 + 2 + 3}
\addintegers{1 + 22 + 333}
\bye
```

This is of course a rather restricted solution (no coverage for example of subtraction unless there is a `+` sign too) but more detail would be needed in the question to go further. Full error-checking would need something a bit more complex.

If the e-TeX primitives are available the same can be achieved expandably with virtually no effort

```
\def\inteval#1{\number\numexpr#1\relax}
\inteval{1}
\inteval{1 + 2 + 3}
\inteval{1 + 22 + 333}
\bye
```

in which case the calculation can include `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(` and `)` as supported by e-TeX (hence the different name). (e-TeX also allows whitespace in expressions.)

---

If you want to work expandably and to use only Knuth's TeX then it is doable if a bit tedious. Heiko Oberdiek's `bigintcalc` can do calculations on arbitrary integers expandably and without using e-TeX, so we could harness that (it's quite big):

```
\input bigintcalc.sty %
\catcode`\@=11 %
\def\addintegers#1{%
  \addintegers@auxi#1+\relax+\stop{0}%
}
\def\addintegers@auxi#1+{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \expandafter\addintegers@end
  \else
    \expandafter\addintegers@auxii
  \fi
    {#1}%
}
\def\addintegers@auxii#1#2\stop#3{%
  \addintegers@auxi#2\stop{\bigintcalcAdd{#1}{#3}}%
}
\def\addintegers@end#1\stop#2{#2}
\catcode`\@=12 %
\addintegers{1}
\addintegers{1 + 2 + 3}
\addintegers{1 + 22 + 333}

\bye
```

The detail in `bigintcalc` comes down to splitting the input into individual digits and doing the maths 'by hand' if `\numexpr` is not available.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, I'll read through this.